# ClickToEdit button with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I'm creating a custom binding that will display an anchor that when clicked turns into a textbox. Once the user enters a value and hits the enter key the value would be pushed into the observableArray that is passed to the binding.

The majority of the binding was taken from Ryan Niemeyers example - found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/2jg2F/2/)

**html**

```
<div data-bind="clickToEdit: { data: items, buttonText: 'New Item' }"></div>
```

**binding**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickToEdit = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};

        var editing = ko.observable(false);
        var newValue = ko.observable();

        var button = $('<a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">' + options.buttonText + '</a>').prepend('<span class="icon-plus"></span>').appendTo(element)[0];
        var input = $('<input type="text">').appendTo(element)[0];

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(button, {
            hidden: editing,
            click: function () {
                editing(true);
            }
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(input, {
            value: newValue,
            visible: editing,
            hasFocus: editing,
            //valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
            onEnter: function(data) {
                debugger;
                options.data.push(data);
                editing(false);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

The problem is that in the function that is bound to the `onEnter` binding the data parameter is always undefined so the new value is never pushed into the array.

Please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/cpXns/) for a complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that can help:

- The `applyBindingsToNode` call accepts a third argument where you can provide the context. In some of my samples, the context was irrelevant, because it was writing directly to an observable and did not need the data.  So, you can pass `context` (or `viewModel`) in as the third argument to your second `applyBindingsToNode` call.
- If I understand what you are trying to do though, then I would think that you could just do something like:  `options.data.push(new Item(newValue());` and not need to worry about the context/data (which would be the overall view model, as you are in the top-level scope).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Pmns4/

Comment: Perfect, your second bullet was square on. Thank you

Comment: By doing `new Item(newValue())` the binding is now tighlty coupled to the model. Isn't this bad practice? Would there be a more preferred way so the binding knows nothing about the model?

Comment: I can think of the obvious way by passing in as an option the new Item to add, maybe something like this... `data-bind="clickToEdit: { data: items, newItem: new Item({}), buttonText: 'New Item' }`. This seems messy though

Comment: I would probably do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/E4PD5/ where you pass an "enterHandler" instead of the array and make sure that your handler always passes the input's value as the first argument (I used "bind" to make that happen)

Comment: Much better idea :) Thank you again